# Check if File exists in AWS S3 Storage with Amplify

Tags: swift, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS S3 Storage with Amplify and to avoid multiple uploads of the same file i want to check if the file already exists.

Currently by getting the download url via Amplify but it also generates an url if the file doesn't exists. I was hoping it returns an error:

```
_ = Amplify.Storage.getURL(key: "myKey") { event in
switch event {
case let .success(url):
    print("Completed: \(url)")
case let .failure(storageError):
    print("Failed: \(storageError.errorDescription). \(storageError.recoverySuggestion)")
}
```

}

Are there any other ways to check if files exists in amplify?

Without downloading it of course.
The whole point is to save traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be able to do something similar with `Amplify.Storage.list` as shown here https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/list/q/platform/ios

```swift
_ = Amplify.Storage.list { event in
    switch event {
    case .success(let listResult):
        let keys = listResult.items.map { $0.key }
        if !keys.contains("myKey") {
            // upload unique file
        }
        
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Failed: \(error.errorDescription).")
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach would work. I got a list with all uploaded objects to check against.

Comment: This is a very inefficient approach if you have a lot of items in your bucket. If you're working at scale, don't do it this way. As of Jan 2023 there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/6830) to add a `.head` method that should help here, but this answer should be used with caution.

Answer (score 0):

You can now check if file exist with `validateObjectExistence` parameter.

Example from [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/ios/#generate-a-download-url):

```
let url = try await Amplify.Storage.getURL(
    key: "ExampleKey",
    options: .init(
        pluginOptions: AWSStorageGetURLOptions(
            validateObjectExistence: true
        )
    )
)
```

*When creating a downloadable URL, you can choose to check if the file exists by setting validateObjectExistence to true in AWSStorageGetURLOptions. If the file is inaccessible or does not exist, a StorageError is thrown. This allows you to check if an object exists during generating the presigned URL, which you can then use to download that object.*